# Evenly-spaced table rows, where table encompasses entire available height

Tags: openoffice, libreoffice, libreoffice-writer, openoffice-writer

Consider a page which may have a header, footer, and a list of questions with a heading:

```
Some Company Header

These are your questions:

1. What is your name?






2. What is your quest?






3. What is the airspeed velocity of an unladen swallow?






Some Company Footer
```

**I would like each question to have an equal amount of space (blank lines for the reader to write in with a pencil) presented after each question.** Automatic question numbering would be nice, but it is not a hard requirement. All the questions should appear on a single printed page. **How can this be done?**

I have tried to use a table for the questions with vertically-positioned text but I see no way to have the table automatically adjust its height to the the full available height on the page. Of course, I could simply count linefeeds to manually add the space, but I'm a software developer and worry about what will happen when I need to add an arbitrary amount of questions in the future :)

I am using LibreOffice 4.1 in Kubuntu Linux, but I would be open to an OpenOffice way of doing the same, as we have some Windows machines running OpenOffice (*not* MS Office).

Comment: Don't know the answer, but 1) it sounds like something that needs a macro (and I don't know LO macros.) 2) There are a number of experts over at https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewforum.php?f=7&sid=18a59f60c5881bbcdc865a5aa7467453  - try asking there.